# Number of Subgroups in $(\mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_2) \rtimes \mathbb Z_2$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product

In the $2$-group $G$ of order $32$ which has Id$ [32,5]$,  and could be describe as:

$$\begin{align}
G &\cong  \langle {a,b,x:a^8,b^2,x^2,[a,b]=[a,x], ...} \rangle \\
&\cong   (\mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_2) \rtimes \mathbb Z_2.
\end{align}$$

I am trying to show that one of the non-normal subgroups of order $4$ is permutable in $G$. So, I am trying to identify possible subgroups that need to be checked. My question is: Is there any information on how to calculate the number of subgroups of such $G$?

Thank you.

Comment: The fastest will be on the computer. In GAP: `g:=SmallGroup(32,5);;List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g),x->[Size(Representative(x)),Size(x)]);` gives you 5 normal subgroups of order 4, and 3 classes, each containing two subgroups of order 4.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of answer you are looking for here.  Why are you trying to find these groups?  What is the motivation for the problem?  If you just need an enumeration of these groups, then a computer-based solution is fine.  But if you are looking for something deeper, can you please explain that?